# How to customize incollection in authordate Chicago style

Tags: biblatex, biber, chicago-style

i am using the author-date chicago style for the bibliography of my thesis, and everything is fine.

I have just one small details: my supervisors asked me change the in collection entries, to put the name of the editors of the volume before the title.

Right know, the chicago revolt style generates the following entry for in collections:

Wyatt, Nicolas. 1999. “The Religion of Ugarit: An Overview.” In *Handbook of Ugaritic Studies*, edited by Wilfred G. E. Watson and Nicolas Wyatt, 529–585. Leiden: Brill.

While I need:

Wyatt, Nicolas. 1999. “The Religion of Ugarit: An Overview.” In Wilfred G. E. Watson and Nicolas Wyatt (eds) *Handbook of Ugaritic Studies*, 529–585. Leiden: Brill.

Is there an easy way to do that?
or do you know any style that i could use instead?

I am using biber

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % for example
\begin{filecontents}{usermwe.bib}
@incollection{watson_religion_1999,
  location = {{Leiden}},
  title = {The {{Religion}} of {{Ugarit}}: An {{Overview}}},
  isbn = {90-04-10988-9},
  timestamp = {2016-10-05T21:11:58Z},
  langid = {english},
  booktitle = {Handbook of {{Ugaritic Studies}}},
  publisher = {{Brill}},
  author = {Wyatt, Nicolas},
  editor = {Watson, Wilfred G. E. and Wyatt, Nicolas},
  date = {1999},
  pages = {529--585},
  keywords = {handbook,Ugarit}
}
\end{filecontents}
% But note that the pages should be the complete page range.

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2,useprefix, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{usermwe.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{watson_religion_1999}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: just added a mwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we need to modify the driver for `@incollection`, we essentially just move the two lines

```
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
```

up a bit and modify a few `\newunit`s.

This ends up with

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthand:author}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{nameaddon}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifundef\bbx@lasthash{\usebibmacro{italtitle+stitle}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifundef\bbx@lasthash{}{\usebibmacro{italtitle+stitle}}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}% 16th ed.
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{part+editor+translator}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\iffieldundef{crossref}}%
    or
    togl {cms@crossref}%
  }%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\iffieldundef{xref}}%
      or
      togl {cms@crossref}%
    }%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}% Moved here.
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{chapincoll}%
  \usebibmacro{mtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}%
  \newcunit
  \iffieldundef{edition}%
  {}%
  {\usebibmacro{edition}}%
  \newcunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{volume+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{ser+num}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{origpubl+loc+year}% 16th ed.
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bibreprint}%
  \usebibmacro{publ+loc+year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \iftoggle{cms@isbn}%
  {\printfield{isbn}}%
  {}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bib+doi+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}%
{\ifboolexpr{% Changed for 16th ed.
    test {\ifterm}%
    or
    test {\ifpunctmark{*}}%
  }%
  {\setunit{\addspace\bibsentence}}%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibprexref}%
  \bibxrefcite{\thefield{xref}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibpostxref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}}%
{\ifboolexpr{% Changed for 16th ed.
    test {\ifterm}%
    or
    test {\ifpunctmark{*}}%
  }%
  {\setunit{\addspace\bibsentence}}%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibprexref}%
  \bibxrefcite{\thefield{crossref}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibpostxref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}}
\makeatother
```

In total with the same modification for `@inbook`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} % for example
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{watson_religion_1999,
  location = {{Leiden}},
  title = {The {{Religion}} of {{Ugarit}}: An {{Overview}}},
  isbn = {90-04-10988-9},
  timestamp = {2016-10-05T21:11:58Z},
  langid = {english},
  booktitle = {Handbook of {{Ugaritic Studies}}},
  publisher = {{Brill}},
  author = {Wyatt, Nicolas},
  editor = {Watson, Wilfred G. E. and Wyatt, Nicolas},
  date = {1999},
  pages = {529--585},
  keywords = {handbook,Ugarit}
}
\end{filecontents}
% But note that the pages should be the complete page range.

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2,useprefix, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthand:author}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{nameaddon}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifundef\bbx@lasthash{\usebibmacro{italtitle+stitle}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifundef\bbx@lasthash{}{\usebibmacro{italtitle+stitle}}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}% 16th ed.
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{part+editor+translator}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\iffieldundef{crossref}}%
    or
    togl {cms@crossref}%
  }%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\iffieldundef{xref}}%
      or
      togl {cms@crossref}%
    }%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}% Moved here.
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{chapincoll}%
  \usebibmacro{mtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}%
  \newcunit
  \iffieldundef{edition}%
  {}%
  {\usebibmacro{edition}}%
  \newcunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{volume+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{ser+num}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{origpubl+loc+year}% 16th ed.
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bibreprint}%
  \usebibmacro{publ+loc+year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \iftoggle{cms@isbn}%
  {\printfield{isbn}}%
  {}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bib+doi+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}%
{\ifboolexpr{% Changed for 16th ed.
    test {\ifterm}%
    or
    test {\ifpunctmark{*}}%
  }%
  {\setunit{\addspace\bibsentence}}%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibprexref}%
  \bibxrefcite{\thefield{xref}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibpostxref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}}%
{\ifboolexpr{% Changed for 16th ed.
    test {\ifterm}%
    or
    test {\ifpunctmark{*}}%
  }%
  {\setunit{\addspace\bibsentence}}%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibprexref}%
  \bibxrefcite{\thefield{crossref}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibpostxref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthand:author}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{nameaddon}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifundef\bbx@lasthash{\usebibmacro{italtitle+stitle}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{cmsbibsortdate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifundef\bbx@lasthash{}{\usebibmacro{italtitle+stitle}}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}% 16th ed.
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{part+editor+translator}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\iffieldundef{crossref}}%
    or
    togl {cms@crossref}%
  }%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\iffieldundef{xref}}%
      or
      togl {cms@crossref}%
    }%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{chapincoll}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{mtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}%
  \newcunit
  \iffieldundef{edition}%
  {}%
  {\usebibmacro{edition}}%
  \newcunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{volume+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{ser+num}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{origpubl+loc+year}% 16th ed.
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bibreprint}%
  \usebibmacro{publ+loc+year}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \iftoggle{cms@isbn}%
  {\printfield{isbn}}%
  {}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bib+doi+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}%
{\ifboolexpr{% Changed for 16th ed.
    test {\ifterm}%
    or
    test {\ifpunctmark{*}}%
  }%
  {\setunit{\addspace\bibsentence}}%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibprexref}%
  \bibxrefcite{\thefield{xref}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibpostxref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}}%
{\ifboolexpr{% Changed for 16th ed.
    test {\ifterm}%
    or
    test {\ifpunctmark{*}}%
  }%
  {\setunit{\addspace\bibsentence}}%
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibprexref}%
  \bibxrefcite{\thefield{crossref}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibpostxref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{cms@related}%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \newunit}%
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{originally+published+as}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\cite{watson_religion_1999}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]